# JTextPane getSelectedText with HTML tags

Tags: java, html

I have a JTextPane containing HTML formatted text.
I would like to allow the user to copy text from the pane, replacing the
`<br />` with `\n` character.
For that, I am using a TransferHandler.

The TransferHandler works fine. My only concern is that if I want to get the HTML formatted content of the JTextPane I have to use its getText() method.
If I use its getSelectedText() method, I only receive plain text with no `<br />` tags which is a problem since I want to keep the formatting when the user copy the content of the pane.

Is there a way to get the selected text of a JTextPane with its html tags ?

Comment: I'm confused, when you copy HTML text with `<br />`, do you want the paste to show the string `<br />` or to replace it with an (invisible but functional) `\n`?

Comment: I replace it with the TransferHandler so that when the user paste the selected text, he gets the same formatting as seen in the JTextPane and no html tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, quite a hacky one.

Instead of formatting the displayed text with `<br />` tags, I put each line in a seperate `<div>`.
This way, when copying text from the JTextPane, the pasted text will preserve the lines formatting.